# Double brackets followed by brackets in R

Tags: r, histogram

I have attached a screenshot of the dataframe I am referring to. [image: dataframe]

Running a statement like `hist(don$TGiving[don$TGiving!=0][don$TGiving[don$TGiving!=0]<=1000])` generates a histogram like the following one:[image: histogram]

I am unable to understand how to interpret the double square brackets [ ][[ ]] in the expression. I do know how [[ ]] works but cannot make sense of [][[ ]] in R.

Thank you.

Comment: I think that your statement is missing a `]`.  Your screenshots did not come through.  This is just subsetting which you can read about by typing `?[`

Comment: I find this explanation helpful (remember that data frames are just lists) http://r4ds.had.co.nz/vectors.html#lists

Comment: Looks like it's `don$TGiving[don$TGiving!=0 & don$TGiving<=1000]`?

Comment: @G5W: have corrected them now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a vector `v`, and a logical vector `lv` of the same length as `v`,
`v[lv]` returns a subset of `v` keeping only rows where `lv` is `TRUE`.  Let's name `v_lv` the vector returned by `v[lv]`. `v_lv` has a length equal to `sum(lv==TRUE)`.
Now if you have, as in your example, `v[lv][v[lv]<x]`, you can rewrite it as `v_lv[v_lv<x]`.
This is again a subset of `v_lv` keeping only rows where the logical expression `(v_lv<x)` is `TRUE`.

In your example, you subset once the vector `don$TGiving` to keep only the rows that are different from 0, and then you subset again the resulting vector to keep only the rows that are `<=10000`. You could also do both subsettings at once, `v[lv1][lv2]` is the same as `v[lv1 & lv2]`.